# AppleScript - Copy All files/folders from source folder to destination folder

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to write an AppleScript that will simply copy the contents (both folders and files) from a specified source folder to a specified destination folder. At the moment my script runs but only copies one file and I can't work out how to get it to copy all files in the folder.

Here's my script:

```
set sourceFolder to (POSIX file "/Users/benny/Desktop/Projects/Source/Project1") as alias
set destinationFolder to (POSIX file "/Users/benny/Documents/Masters/Project1") as alias

tell application "System Events"
    set availableSourceFiles to every file of sourceFolder whose visible is true
    set filesOfTargetFolder to files of destinationFolder whose visible is true
end tell

-- if no more source file is available, quit this script
if (count of availableSourceFiles) = 0 then
    quit
end if

set sourceFile to (first item of availableSourceFiles) as alias
-- use the Finder to copy the file
tell application "Finder"
    -- duplicate the file to the target folder
    duplicate sourceFile to destinationFolder
end tell
```

I'm assuming I need to include a `for each` type loop but can't get the syntax correct here. Haven't written AppleScripts in many years so trying to remember how it all works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the destination `"Project1"` folder doesn't have stuff in it already, then duplicating the folder is likely to be quicker:

```
tell application id "com.apple.Finder" to duplicate folder POSIX file ¬
        "/Users/benny/Desktop/Projects/Source/Project1" to the folder ¬
        POSIX file "/Users/benny/Documents/Masters" with replacing
```

However, if that's not an option, then I'd stick with your method and copy the contents of the folder across instead:

```
set here to POSIX file "/Users/benny/Desktop/Projects/Source/Project1"
set there to POSIX file "/Users/benny/Documents/Masters"

tell application id "com.apple.Finder" to duplicate ¬
             every item in the folder here to there
```

Bear in mind that if there's a file or folder at any of the destinations that intended to be occupied by one of the incoming source items, *Finder* will throw an error.  You would typically incorporate some sort of check ahead of the copy.